# Trouble subsetting in python when using R

Tags: r, rpy2

I have a float vector as below:

```
v = robjects.FloatVector([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5,
    6.6,3.1,1.2,4.7,8.4,1.1,2.3,1.1,4.0,2,1.1,14,1.0])
```

`type(v)` gives:

```
rpy2.robjects.vectors.FloatVector
```

and b a boolean vector as below:

```
 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

`type(b)` gives:

```
rpy2.robjects.vectors.BoolVector
```

when I try to subset V using b as `v[b]` it says :

> TypeError: SexpVector indices must be integers, not BoolVector

How do i get items of V where b is True please?

Thanks in advance.
Raghu

Comment: try `as.numeric(b)`

Comment: I am inside python and using rpy2. So all these objects are wrapped as if they are python objects. as.numeric(b) did not work. Thanks for looking.

Comment: I am using stackoverflow for the first time and hence I apologise for any confusion in the question. It should have perhaps read as 'Trying to use R inside python'. Sincere apologies.